# Granting access to Google Cloud Console's Panel for Cloud Identity Aware Proxy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-iap

It seems only a project with Owner role can toggle IAP for resources listed at [Cloud Platform Console IAP Panel](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iap/). What role in IAM can grant a member user access to make edits in this console panel? Or are project Owners the only users who have edit access in this particular console panel?

Answer (score 0):

The IAP access policy is really just part of the project's IAM policy. So, it's controlled by who can set IAM policy on the project. Per https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-proj, I believe that this is just Owner.

Do you have a use case where you want a different set of people to control IAP policy v. general project policy? That might be something we could consider for the future.
  -- Matthew, Identity-Aware Proxy team